# jQuery deferred (no promises)

Tags: jquery

The following works, but I'm wondering if I'm using the deferred object the right way:

```
var dbo = openDatabase('dbName','1.0','Description goes here', 1048576);

console.log(jQuery.fn.jquery); // 1.7.1
var myDeferred = new jQuery.Deferred();

dbo.transaction(function(myTrans) {
    myTrans.executeSql(
        'CREATE table IF NOT EXISTS myTable(myTableID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ASC, myTableName Varchar(20))',
        [],
        function(myTransaction,myResult) {
            myDeferred.resolve(myTransaction,myResult)
        },
        function(myTransaction,myResult) {
            myDeferred.reject(myTransaction,myResult)
        }
    );
});

myDeferred.done(function(A,B) {
    console.log('.done');
    console.log(A);
    console.log(B);
});

myDeferred.fail(function(A,B) {
    console.log('.fail');
    console.log(A);
    console.log(B);
});
```